# Presented UIViewController not getting deallocated on dismissal

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

First off, I've read many answers on SO and I still can't seem to solve this problem.

In my appDelegate, if the user is not signed in, I present `WelcomeViewController` from the window's rootViewController, which is an instance of [MMDrawerController](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController):

```
WelcomeViewController welcome = [[WelcomeViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:welcome];
[self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:nav animated:false completion:nil];
// NSLog(@"self.window.root: %@", self.window.rootViewController); 
// gives <MMDrawerController: 0xdf578e0>
```

At some point, the user either skips or successfully logs in, in which case I fire this code from WelcomeViewController:

```
// WelcomeViewController.m
- (void)userSuccessfullySignedIn
{
    [self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:self.successBlock];
    // NSLog(@"self.presentingViewController: %@", self.presentingViewController); 
    // gives <MMDrawerController: 0xdf578e0>
}
```

I thought I was doing things right by calling dismiss on the `presentingViewController` instead of `self`, but dealloc is never getting called:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"dealloc was called");
}
```

As a result, my instance of WelcomeViewController is staying in memory even though I've dismissed it. As you can see from my console output, presenting and dismissing is happening from the same instance of MMDrawerController.

What do I need to do to properly dismiss it AND have it's memory released?

Comment: you say that you are presenting the welcome controller from your root view controller, but the code you posted is presenting the navigation controller. Is this a typo?

Comment: no, not a typo, just didn't think it mattered. In `userSuccessfullySignedIn` if I log `self.navigationController.presentingViewController` I still get the same instance of MMDrawerController. Welcome and the Nav do in fact dismiss and are removed from the screen, it's just that their memory is never reallocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an aggravating day, it turns out it was a bug in Taplytics v1.2.24. The bug was fixed in 1.2.32.

They have a category on UIBarButtonItem where they do some method swizzling, and were holding a strong reference to the target of the rightBarButtonItem (which was my viewController). That in turn was preventing my UIViewController from deallocating.

Answer (score -1):

Dismissing a view controller is *not* the same as deallocating. You need to set presentingViewController to `nil.`

Comment: Point taken about dismissing not being the same as deallocating, but `presentingViewController` is readonly and cannot be set to nil.

Comment: Yeah I completely misinterpreted this... misread present*ing* as present*ed*. setting that to nil wouldn't do anything even if it wasn't readonly. It is strange that it isn't being deallocated... the view controller doing the presenting's strong reference should be gone now, so unless you've made another strong reference to it somewhere it should be deallocated I would think.

Comment: @BenPious there is a Edit button below your text. If you have misprinted, you always able to fix it and clean your karma. You're welcome.